# Can not complete this action error while deleting SharePoint list item

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I delete a SharePoint list item I get an error after about 30 min.

> Cannot complete this action.

I am trying to delete the item with administrator user.

The error is raised on one list only.

[image]

Comment: One specified item or all items on the list ?

Comment: All items in the list

Comment: Other lists on same site have same problem ? You can add or edit item in the specified list without error ? Have some custom feature installed for the specified list ? Need more clues.

Comment: no, other lists are working fine. Add edit working but only delete issue. No custom feature installed.

Comment: Check the uls log, the event viewer on sharepoint server and the event viewer on sql server for any related error. Also download sharepoint manager on codeplex to check if any custom event handler is attached to the list.